# Mysql is not converting timestamp to the timezone of PHP query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime, timestamp-with-timezone

[I have a mysql database in this format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/taHfr.png)

And I am trying to fetch the values through a php document and convert them into json on the timezone of the user (or maybe just GMT-6 would suffice) but the json outputs from the php document are as follows:

```
[{"timestamp":"2018-06-13 19:52:05","temperature":"79.83","humidity":"41.89","pressure":"99.35"},{"timestamp":"2018-06...
```

Still in UTC time, I have tried adding

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
```

To the php document, but the time never changes, how would I solve this?

Comment: Thats because you need to fetch them and setting the date with the proper function, another way is change the timezone of your MySQL Server

Comment: PHP treats timestamps coming from the database as strings, it doesn't parse them as times, so it doesn't do any timezone processing.

Comment: why didn't you set the timezone on the sql server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`convert_tz()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz) on the timestamps in your query to convert them from one timezone to another, e.g.:

```
... convert_tz(`timestamp`, 'Etc/UTC', 'America/Los_Angeles') ...
```

Make sure to follow the procedure "Populating the Time Zone Tables" as described in ["5.1.12 MySQL Server Time Zone Support"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time-zone-support.html) to have the time zones available or to check which are available in your system.

Comment: `Etc` should be `UTC`?

Comment: @Barmar: I don't know which names are available at the OPs system, it's just an example. I followed [that list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) where it's `Etc/UTC`. But just `UTC` likely works as well.